# How to filter out dataframe based on latest file in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I need to filter out dataframe based on latest file. Could you please help me how to do this?

Example:

```
             filename                                                      Is_Active     Program Type
SR0661000_risdiplam__Consolidated_Patient_Input_for_Posting_20210521.pdf     A      Oncology
SR0661000_risdiplam__Consolidated_Patient_Input_for_Posting_20210514.pdf     A
```

In output I want-

```
             filename                                                      Is_Active    Program Type
SR0661000_risdiplam__Consolidated_Patient_Input_for_Posting_20210521.pdf     A     Oncology
```

I need to filter this dataframe based on latest filename.

Comment: How do you determine the `latest file`  from the filename ?

Comment: based on the date which is added in the last of every file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your filenames are in the format you have in your question, you can try:

```py
out = df.sort_values(
    by="filename", key=lambda s: s.str.split("_").str[-1], ascending=False
).head(1)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                                            filename Is_Active Program Type
0  SR0661000_risdiplam__Consolidated_Patient_Inpu...         A     Oncology
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format is fixed you can:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'filename': ['SR0661000_risdiplam__Consolidated_Patient_Input_for_Posting_20210521.pdf', 
                 'SR0661000_risdiplam__Consolidated_Patient_Input_for_Posting_20210514.pdf',
                 'A_20210521.pdf',
                 'A_20210522.pdf'],
    'Is_Active': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'],  
})
cols = df.columns
df['creation_time'] = df['filename'].apply(lambda x: x.split("_")[-1].split(".")[0])
df['fname'] =  df['filename'].apply(lambda x: "_".join(x.split("_")[:-1]))

df[df.groupby(['fname'])['creation_time'].transform(max) == df['creation_time']][cols]
```

output:

```
                                        filename    Is_Active
0   SR0661000_risdiplam__Consolidated_Patient_Inpu...   A
3   A_20210522.pdf                                      A
```